# Spring configuration for spring-mongo-data service

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-mongo

I was using stackoverflow before. it is long time I did not to post a question. I use mongodb with spring mvc 4.0.3 framework. I get errors I think because of my spring configuration xml. I was following [this tutorial](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com.tr/2011/10/integrating-mongodb-spring.html) let me share my codes with you so that you can help me to find out what my problem can be. Thanks...

```
@Transactional
public interface IPersonService extends MongoRepository<Person, String>{

}
```

>

```
@Service
@Repository("personService")
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private IPersonService personService;
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public List<Person> getAllPersons() throws Exception{
        return this.personService.findAll();
    }

    public Person findPersonById(String personId) throws Exception{
        if(personId == null || personId.equals(""))
            throw new Exception("wrong id");
        Person person = mongoTemplate.findById(personId, Person.class);
        if(person == null)
            throw new Exception("user is not find");
        return person;
    }

    public Person updatePerson(Person person) throws Exception{
        Person dbPerson = findPersonById(person.getId());
        if(dbPerson == null)
            throw new Exception("xxx : update user failed");
        return personService.save(person);
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>serviceofsps</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spsdispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spsdispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->

    <listener>
         <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
 </web-app>
```

**spsdispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd">
      <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <!-- <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> -->

   <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:/messages/messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
     <bean class= "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" > 
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" /> 
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
     </bean>

</beans>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- spring frameworka properties dosyasını tanıtma -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/application.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property> 
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="inno.delux.ws" >

    </context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

    <!-- Loads MongoDB configuraton -->
    <import resource="mongo-config.xml"/>
</beans>
```

**Exception:**

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private inno.delux.ws.repository.IPersonService inno.delux.ws.service.UserService.personService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [inno.delux.ws.repository.IPersonService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private inno.delux.ws.repository.IPersonService inno.delux.ws.service.UserService.personService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [inno.delux.ws.repository.IPersonService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [inno.delux.ws.repository.IPersonService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: You haven't shown what is in the `mongo-config.xml`

Comment: @Artem you are right about repositories. Taking the scan off. Thanks, learnt something new.

Comment: when I  do not inject 'private IPersonService personService;' I can use mongorepository in my userservice, it means I do not have a problem about mongo-config.xml because I can nonnect and make query.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add mongodb repository scanning:

Add in `applicationContext.xml` the XML schema and the tag `repositories` for scanning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

  <mongo:mongo id="mongo" />

  <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg value="databaseName" />
  </bean>

  <mongo:repositories base-package="com.acme.*.repositories" />

</beans>
```

Example from the [spring data mongodb project](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html).

Comment: when I add these beans boundry content, I can add <repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" /> but other tags gives error and vice-verse also. what should I do?

Comment: @Kartoch, the question is about MongoDb, but you suggest JPA. However, of course, the tag is the same. @demlik, you should declare `xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"` and its `<mongo:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />`

Comment: because I can not see much reasonable thing about coding of spring. I like some parts of it but working with xml is so bad. I dont know what I should add what I should not. what is effecting where is just something that can be known by just creator of spring or I should read  2 3 times a book of whole spring and then try to build some projects with it so that I can learn.

Comment: If you start to use `MongoRepository<?, ?>` you must know how it works. Spring (or any other framework) can't do evrything for you.